# Android GoogleMaps V2 maker object reference lost

Tags: java, android, google-maps-api-2, marker

I´m developing an app that uses Google Maps V2. When the map fragment it´s loaded and the markers are painted, I´ve got a button on the action bar that calls another activity for results that will act as a place finder.

On this activity result, I search on my `mMarkers` which is a `HashMap<Long, Marker>` like this:

```
if (mMarkers.containsKey(place.id)) {
    mMarkers.get(place.id).showInfoWindow();
    mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(updateCamera(new LatLng(place.lat, place.lng))));
} else {
    Marker marker = mMap.addMarker(
        new MarkerOptions()
        .position(markerPos)
        .title(place.name)
    );
    marker.showInfoWindow();
    mMarkers.put(place.id, marker); // if it´s not on the map I put it
    mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(updateCamera(new LatLng(place.lat, place.lng))));
}
```

I show the markers infoWindow because I´ve got a `onInfoWindowClick` implemented.

Here comes the main problem. This is my `onInfoWindowClick` event:

```
@Override
public void onInfoWindowClick(Marker marker) {
    Long placeId = null;
    if (mMarkers.containsValue(marker)) {
        Iterator<Entry<Long, Marker>> it = mMarkers.entrySet().iterator();
        while (it.hasNext()) {
            Map.Entry<Long, Marker> pairs = (Map.Entry<Long, Marker>)it.next();
            if (pairs.getValue().getId().equals(marker.getId())) {
                placeId = pairs.getKey();
            }
        }
        if (placeId != null) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, PlaceActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("placeId", placeId);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    }
}
```

When I check the `mMarkers.containsValue(marker)` the reference to the marker object it´s different from the one I´ve got on the same map on the above `onActivityResult` function.

I´m not creating any new instance of that marker object so I don't really understand why it changes that reference.

***--- UPDATE ---***

I´ve tried without showing the infoWindow and it works perfect. Any ideas why this happens or any workaround to this?

Lots of thanks in regard!!

Comment: Have you tried to make a simple loop to check if the Objects are equal or not ? I mean like this : 
`for (Marker m : mMarkers) if (dummyMarker.equals(m))`...

Comment: @Sw4Tish I actually do it on the infoWindowClicked event. But it doesn't find it. Everything works when I don't call the showInfoWindow() method.

Comment: The marker object passed in through the listener may not be the same instance as the one you created (https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/marker#event_handling). You need to use `equals()` to check for equality of the markers.

Comment: @JasonHanley it may change when the object is passed through a listener but the strange thing is that when I don't call showInfoWindow the reference after passed doesn't change.